# I can execute bash step by step manually, but not in the script?

Tags: bash, macos

This [script](https://www.jakobstoeck.de/2017/ramdisk-for-faster-applications-under-macos/) is to create a ramdisk in /Volumes/

```sh
#!/bin/bash
VOLUME_NAME=RamDisk
SIZE_IN_MB=1024
DEVICE=`hdiutil attach -nobrowse -nomount ram://$(($SIZE_IN_MB*2048))`
sudo diskutil erasevolume HFS+ $VOLUME_NAME $DEVICE
```

I can run this script step by step manually in the terminal, without any problem. But when I run a script, it seems like $DEVICE was not successfully captured as excepted.

I use  DEVICE=$(..) but the same error still happens.

> The third parameter does not appear to be "bootable" or "nonbootable"

I am using macos 10.14 default bash 3.2. I have been debugging this silly problem for more than an hour.

Comment: Add `set -x` to see what's happening in detail.

Comment: Also, nitpick but use `$(...)` rather than `\`...\``

Comment: I see. The original script have no problem. I failed to mention I have "imported" my commonly used function (thousands of line) at the front as usual, which includes a line of **IFS=$'\n\t'**,  and that is the problem. I have forgot why I want  this line for general purpose.

Comment: Ah, yeah, don't override `$IFS`. Changing it globally is a big mistake. If you figure out why you have it and want to ask about alternatives that'd be a good question.

Comment: http://redsymbol.net/articles/unofficial-bash-strict-mode/  told me to add it. I thought it is a strict mode for good habit.

Comment: Ew. What a bad idea.

Comment: maybe now you have , with your 1000s of lines of code, understand why it is a bad idea override system defaults :-) ? Glad you solved your problem.

Comment: Thank you. After a deeper reading, I think I just need to double quotes the variable, rather than overriding $IFS. Overriding $IFS every time is pointless because shellcheck tool could help me detect such mistake easily.

Comment: Oh boy, that "bash strict mode" is **terrible** advice. Quote quote quote.

Comment: I wrote to the author of the article a couple months ago explaining why it's bad advice. I got back, "Thanks for taking the time to write this. Great feedback and comments!" Yet the article remains. Oh well.